# Why is my SHAP plot in Python returning grey instead of red and blue?

Tags: python, plot, shap

So I was plotting a SHAP plot in Python, just like [this tutorial](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_notebooks/tabular_examples/tree_based_models/Catboost%20tutorial.html). However, instead of returning red and blue values (like the tutorial), my plot is grey. I didn't find any post talking about this so I've decided to open this one, even though I can't share my data due to my country regulation and company rules. Since this is a generic question, I still believe I can open this post and perhaps help others. If I'm wrong and this post violated any rule, I sincerely apologize.